# What is the meaning of the handwritten notation on the pension record of Charles Clements?

Tags: united-states, 18th-century, palaeography, american-revolution, pension-records

I am trying to interpret this US Revolutionary War pension payment record:

[image]

I am interested in the date of death of Charles Clements of Flauvanna, Virginia. The line for him ends with this notation:

[image]

The last payment number is shown in March 1848, which leads me to interpret the handwritten notation as "25 June 48", followed by something illegible to me. According to [a Sons of the American Revolution application](https://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?viewrecord=1&r=an&db=SARMemberApps&indiv=try&h=555016), Charles Clements died in 1848.

**What is the handwritten notation for Charles Clements above, and what does it mean?**

The source of the record is:

> The National Archives; Washington, D.C.; Ledgers of Payments,
>   1818-1872, to U.S. Pensioners Under Acts of 1818 Through 1858 From
>   Records of the Office of the Third Auditor of the Treasury; Record
>   Group Title: Records of the Accounting Officers of the Department of
>   the Treasury; Record Group Number: 217; Series Number: T718; Roll
>   Number: 7
>
> Ancestry.com. U.S., Revolutionary War Pensioners, 1801-1815, 1818-1872
>   [database on-line]. Provo, UT, USA: Ancestry.com Operations, Inc.,
>   2007.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The descriptive pamphlet for NARA microcopy publication T718 is a reproduction of its entry in the print catalog of microfilm publications.  It contains a roll list and a brief description of the entries in the register.

> Each entry shows the name of the pensioner, the name of the veteran (if different), the name of the pension agent, the name of the pension agency through which payment was made, and the quarter and year of the last payment to the pensioner. When an heir or a legal representative claimed an unpaid balance due the pensioner at the time of death, the date of death of the pensioner is given and the date of the final payment made to the family or heirs.

I read the last part of the entry after the date of death as "to 3rd qr 48", understanding "qr" to mean 'quarter'.

You could try looking for other entries for veterans who had died, and comparing those entries to see what form the information takes.

To find the DP for a NARA microfilm publication, follow these steps:

1. From [NARA's home page](https://www.archives.gov/) choose [Research Our Records](https://www.archives.gov/research)
2. Choose **Microfilm Catalog** and on the top navigation bar choose **Microfilm**.
3. Type the publication number (e.g. T718) in the **Search and Browse Microfilm** box at the left-hand side of the screen. (Ignore the **Order Microfilm** box unless you really want your own copy. We aren't going to make an order, just look at the catalog.)

[image]

Next, choose a title from the list that results. When you get to the next screen, look on the right-hand side for the PDF icon where it says **View Important Publication Details**:

[image]

From there you should be able to download the DP, if one exists.

See also NARA's [Electronic Publications Bibliography](https://www.archives.gov/research/alic/reference/electronic-pubs).